# Linking issue in Cross Compilation for arm in linux using aarch64-linux-gnu-

Tags: linux, gcc

I got an error when try to link (-aarch64-linux-gnu-ld) (*the script containing the Makefile was downloaded from *https://github.com/Icenowy/aw-el2-barebone**). Error is "aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: Error: unable to disambiguate: -nostartfiles (did you mean --nostartfiles ?)
make: *** [Makefile:31: el2-bb.elf] Error 1" How to recode the line 31? of the Makefile

```
CROSS_COMPILE = /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-

DEBUG = 1

CC = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
AS = $(CROSS_COMPILE)as
LD = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ld
OBJCOPY = $(CROSS_COMPILE)objcopy

INCLUDES = -I ./include -I ./uboot-headers -ffreestanding

DEFINES = -DSOC_HEADER="\"h6.h\""

ifneq ($(DEBUG),1)
DEFINES += -DNDEBUG
endif

ASFLAGS = $(INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) -D__ASSEMBLY__
CFLAGS = $(INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) -O2

LDSCRIPT = ldscripts/a64.ld
LDSCRIPTS = ldscripts/a64.ld ldscripts/common.ld

LDFLAGS = -nostdlib -nostartfiles -static -T $(LDSCRIPT)

OBJS = start.o init.o uart.o stack.o exceptions.o exception_funcs.o panic.o pgtables.o  trapped_funcs.o

all: el2-bb.bin

el2-bb.elf: $(OBJS) $(LDSCRIPTS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@

el2-bb.bin: el2-bb.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f el2-bb.* *.o
```

Comment: `-nostartfiles` is not a valid `ld` option.

Comment: "`-nostartfiles (did you mean --nostartfiles`" Sooooooo change `-nostartfiles` to `--nostartfile`? "`How to recode the line 31?`" What do you mean by "recode"?

Comment: Yes I tries changing from -nostartfiles to --nostartfiles and recompiled. But ended with error stating " aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: unrecognized option '--nostartfiles'. I think there seems to be a cording error that I can not catch.

Answer (score 0):

`-nostartfiles` is a `gcc` option but not an `ld` option.

If you use `gcc` to invoke the linker (say with `LD=gcc` in your Makefile) for making a standalone program that does not use standard startup files, you should use `-nostartfiles` because `gcc` links the startup files by default and `-nostartfiles` disables this.

`ld` doesn't links any startup files by default, so there is no option to disable linking them. You always pass startup files explicitly to `ld`. If you don't want startup files, just don't pass them to `ld`.

In order to see what startup files on your system are create an empty C program:

```
int main(){}
```

and compile it:

```
gcc -c empty.c
gcc -v empty.o
```

You are likely to see an invocation of `ld` (or perhaps of `collect2`, which calls `ld`) with a long, *long* list of options and object files.

Now run

```
gcc -nostartfiles -v empty.o
```

The .o files are now gone. That's exactly what `-nostartfiles` does.

When you invoke `ld empty.o`, these files and options are *not there to begin with*. In order to make a working program for say a Linux system, you need to pass most of them to `ld` explicitly. If you are building a program for something other system, you may not need some or all of them. So just don't pass them in.

Comment: Thank you. It is clear to me now.